# How to use AutoFitTextView

Tags: android, resize, textview

Somedays ago, I found this code to resize text inside TextView. But, how can I use it and call it into my project. Im a newbie :)

```
public class AutoFitTextView extends TextView {

public AutoFitTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public AutoFitTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    maxTextSize = this.getTextSize();
    if (maxTextSize < 35) {
        maxTextSize = 30;
    }
    minTextSize = 20;
}

private void refitText(String text, int textWidth) {
   if (textWidth 0) {
       int availableWidth = textWidth - this.getPaddingLeft()
               - this.getPaddingRight();
       float trySize = maxTextSize;

       this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, trySize);
       while ((trySize minTextSize)
               && (this.getPaint().measureText(text) availableWidth)) {
           trySize -= 1;
           if (trySize <= minTextSize) {
               trySize = minTextSize;
               break;
           }
           this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, trySize);
       }
       this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, trySize);
   } }

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before,
        final int after) {
    refitText(text.toString(), this.getWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != oldw) {
        refitText(this.getText().toString(), w);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    refitText(this.getText().toString(), parentWidth);
}

public float getMinTextSize() {
    return minTextSize;
}

public void setMinTextSize(int minTextSize) {
    this.minTextSize = minTextSize;
}

public float getMaxTextSize() {
    return maxTextSize;
}

public void setMaxTextSize(int minTextSize) {
    this.maxTextSize = minTextSize;
}

private float minTextSize;

private float maxTextSize;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout, you use it like a typical `TextView` except you point to the location of your `AutoFitTextView` class.

```
 <com.your.package.name.AutoFitTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in code:

```
AutoFitTextView foo = (AutoFitTextView) findViewById(id);
```

All you really need to do is use it within your layout. If you don't use it within your layout, then don't use it within you code either. So, either use it in your layout and code, only layout, or not at all.

Also, in your layout make sure you're poiting to the correct location. I don't know what package you have your `AutoFitTextView` class in, so I only used `com.your.package.name` as an example.

That's it, easy does it.

Comment: I changed all the textview into Autofittextview, but when I tried to run it, the program raise an error 
04-26 09:29:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 09:29:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1090): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

Comment: I made some edits. If you keep having problems you should just think about what you're doing. Using your class is really simple, use it like a normal `TextView`. I'm sure you can figure it out from here.